# Handling 302 response code for an Ajax response

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, yui, redirect, http-status-code-302

I'm using YUI 2.9.0 in a web application. In case of Ajax calls, when user session got expired, the server sends a 302-Moved Temporarily response with the location parameter set to the login server.

The web app domain and the login server domain are different. I face problem in redirection as firefox does not redirect automatically to the login server (i assume it is because of different domains).

I have verified that redirection happens and my ajax callback functions are getting the new location's content as response, when the redirection is to a different page in the same domain.

Is there any way to work around this problem. I'm sure this will be a very common problem if it is because of cross domain redirect.

Comment: There are work arounds, mostly involving CORS - http://www.oriontransfer.co.nz/blog/2011-05/cross-domain-ajax/index.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code as workaround
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
           //normal flow
      }
    //if 302 found then will run else part
    else{
          //code to redirect
    }